# I'm trying to "re-create" an animation using css3, I have almost zero experience in css. details inside

Tags: css

I'm trying to recreate an animation using css, I have 5 different animations, I'm trying to get it into one css code and position it correct, here's an example of the animation:
`http://gfycat.com/GeneralElegantDiscus`

I have all these:

[BASE](http://i.cubeupload.com/beDAgX.png)
 
[CRYSTAL](http://jsfiddle.net/944mb4m3/) 
 
[ARM1](http://jsfiddle.net/0Lx0dgnq/1/) 
 
[ARM2](http://jsfiddle.net/asc3xfz7/) 
 
[GLOW](http://jsfiddle.net/gqfbhddb/)

[GFYCAT](http://gfycat.com/GeneralElegantDiscus)

I have no idea how to do get it all together and position it, here's how I want it to look with all the pieces together:
`http://i.gyazo.com/f3dd728494367e53d51f23a3697a041b.png`

Can someone help me out?
if the animations are not timed well, its not a problem.

Sorry for my bad english, It's not native.`enter code here`

Help will be much appreciated

Comment: You should leave your question intact once he has been answered, in case someone has a similar problem in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get them all together, you'll need to change your `@-keyframes` with unique animation names (currently, they're all `play`)

Because this is animation, I would recommend you look into `absolute` positioning.

Finally, because you're new/learning CSS, read up on the console and how you can manipulate CSS values using an Inspector (Web Inspector, FireBug, etc.)

Here's something I threw together quickly (only works in Chrome) for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc279p8/

Good luck.